# Drop_duplicates in a dataframe and keep the one with a specific column value

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a dataframe df:

```
columnA columnB columnC columnD columnE
A        B         10      C       C
A        B         10      D       A
B        C         20      A       A
B        A         20      D       A
B        A         20      D       C
```

I want to drop the duplicates if there are duplicates entries for `columnA, columnB, columnC` in my case the duplicates are:

```
columnA columnB columnC columnD columnE
A        B         10      C       C
A        B         10      D       A
B        A         20      D       A
B        A         20      D       C
```

How can I keep the one of the duplicate rows, where `columnE` is equal to `C` ?
So that the output for the full dataframe is:

```
columnA columnB columnC columnD columnE
A        B         10      C       C
B        C         20      A       A
B        A         20      D       C
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) for prefer `C` values first with [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and or original order add [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
out = (df.sort_values('columnE', key=lambda x: x.ne('C'))
         .drop_duplicates(['columnA','columnB','columnC'])
         .sort_index())
print (out)
  columnA columnB  columnC columnD columnE
0       A       B       10       C       C
2       B       C       20       A       A
4       B       A       20       D       C
```

Or use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for indices with prefer `C` with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select rows and [`Series.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) for original ordering:

```
idx = df['columnE'].eq('C').groupby([df['columnA'],df['columnB'],df['columnC']]).idxmax()
out = df.loc[idx.sort_values()]
print (out)
  columnA columnB  columnC columnD columnE
0       A       B       10       C       C
2       B       C       20       A       A
4       B       A       20       D       C
```